# with this code as no idea why. voices = engine.getProperty('voices') KeyError:'VoiceAge'

Tags: python, dynamics-al

I am trying to create a Voice Assistant but cannot get over this error from this code as nothing is helping me out even looking it up.

```
import datetime
import pywhatkit
import wikipedia

listener = sr.Recognizer()
alexa = pyttsx3.init()
voices = alexa.getProperty('voices')
```

Comment: II am getting a KeyError:Value for these codes right here and have no idea what configuration I got them wrong. listener = sr.Recognizer()
alexa = pyttsx3.init()
voices = alexa.getProperty('voices')

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
      print('Device is listening, please speak...')
      voice = listener.listen(source)
      command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
      command = command.lower()
      if 'alexa' in command:
          print(command)
```

except:
pass